# Return a string that is repeated a many times

Tags: c#

I want to insert a number of * before a string based on an items depth and I'm wondering if there is a way to return a string repeated Y times. Example:

```
string indent = "***";
Console.WriteLine(indent.Redraw(0)); //would print nothing.
Console.WriteLine(indent.Redraw(1)); //would print "***".
Console.WriteLine(indent.Redraw(2)); //would print "******".
Console.WriteLine(indent.Redraw(3)); //would print "*********".
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`String` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_):

```
string result = new String('*', 9); // 9 *
```

If you really want to repeat a string n-times:

```
string indent = "***";
string result = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(indent, 3)); // 9 *
```

Comment: That duplicates a _character_ N times, not a _string_.

Comment: @DStanley:  you're right, for the sake of completeness. But was already mentioned in the duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are looking for `PadLeft()` Or, in your case even `PadRight()` will do the trick :

```
string indent = "".PadLeft(20, '*'); //repeat * 20 times
```